# HighCharts does not add a new points

Tags: javascript, highcharts, monitor

I am trying to set up a simple weather station with esp8266 and plot and display the obtained data in graphs. I'm trying to use HighCharts for this task. Now I'm having a problem that HighCharts does not add a new point to the graph.

My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      min-width: 310px;
        max-width: 1280px;
        height: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h2>ESP Weather Station</h2>
    <div id="chart-temperature" class="container"></div>
    <div id="chart-humidity" class="container"></div>
    <div id="chart-pressure" class="container"></div>
<script>
var value1 = <?php echo $value1; ?>;
var value2 = <?php echo $value2; ?>;
var value3 = <?php echo $value3; ?>;
var reading_time = <?php echo $reading_time; ?>;

var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart:{ renderTo : 'chart-temperature' },
  title: { text: 'BME280 Temperature' },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: value1
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: { animation: false,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    },
    series: { color: '#059e8a' }
  },
  xAxis: { 
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: reading_time
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Temperature (Celsius)' }
    //title: { text: 'Temperature (Fahrenheit)' }
  },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});


setInterval(function ( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
          y = parseFloat(this.responseText);
      //console.log(this.responseText);
      
      if(chartT.series[0].data.length > 4) {
        chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
      } else {
        chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/esp-chart.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 3000 ) ;


var chartH = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart:{ renderTo:'chart-humidity' },
  title: { text: 'BME280 Humidity' },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: value2
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: { animation: false,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    //dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: '%H:%M:%S' },
    categories: reading_time
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Humidity (%)' }
  },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});


var chartP = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart:{ renderTo:'chart-pressure' },
  title: { text: 'BME280 Pressure' },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: value3
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: { animation: false,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    },
    series: { color: '#18009c' }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: reading_time
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Pressure (hPa)' }
  },
  credits: { enabled: false },
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm trying to just add a new point to the temperature graph, ignoring humidity and pressure. That's what I get[image] And the point keeps on reloading over and over again. When I reload the page I see normally spaced points, but after a while it moves to one point as shown in the picture. Is there any way to plot the data continuously?

Comment: What is your initial value for the `chartT.series[0].data.length`?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Now set to zero. But no difference is seen if set to another value.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your case to understand the issue and here are my conclusions:

1. Don't use the true flag for a shift in the `addPoint` feature - it deletes the previous point - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint
2. You have defined the `xAxis` type as 'datatime' and trying to assign the categories - it is also a mistake. The category type is a different thing.

   ```
   xAxis: { 
     type: 'datetime',
     categories: reading_time
   },
   ```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/45Ltwbcx/